# How to connect to a MySQL instance using sockets?

Tags: mysql, sockets

The MySQL [docs on socket connections](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-connection-socket.html) state:

*On Unix, MySQL Shell connections default to using Unix sockets when the following conditions are met:
A TCP port is not specified.
A host name is not specified or it is equal to localhost.*

What I don't understand is if this is the case how can I ever specify the hostname I want to connect to if it isn't localhost? I must be missing a beginning step somewhere? I am on a VM in a network that includes the MySQL instance.